# QT Systray icon appears next to launcher on Ubuntu instead of on the panel

Tags: qt, ubuntu, qt5, systray, appindicator

I am new to QT and need to build an app with an app-indicator. As QT seems easier than GTK+, I am making it in QT.

I would mention that I have sni-qt installed and app indicators of vlc and skype appear normal on the panel. I am using QT5 on Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit.

I followed this tutorial step by step: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/desktop-systray.html

But when I run it, here's how it appears (The cross is the icon I am using):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bT33.png]

How do I fix this?

Comment: Which version of Qt is that? Have you tried the latest version (5.1.0-rc1)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm afraid that Qt5 is not supported by sni-qt at the moment, so you either have to wait for a new release that will support it, or code it using gtk+ and libappindicator using [this guide](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/technologies/application-indicators/). There are even examples for various of languages. [Since Qt5 also distributes GLib events](http://qtnode.net/wiki/GLib_Event_Loop) that makes the integration a lot more easier. First you need to find out whether you're running on Unity or not (to support more desktops than just unity), that you can do by retrieving XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP environment variable and if it returns Unity you create appindicator, otherwise create QSystemTrayIcon.

First you need to include required headers:

```
#undefine signals                                                  
extern "C" {                                                                 
  #include <libappindicator/app-indicator.h>                                 
  #include <gtk/gtk.h>                                                       
}                                                                            
#define signals public
```

Since app-indicator directly uses "signals" name we need to undefine the default Qt "keyword" signals which normally translates to public. Then, since we're coding C++ and libappindicator is coded in C we need to use extern "C" not to use C++ name mangling.

Next create the AppIndicator/QSystemTrayIcon based on what desktop are we on:

```
QString desktop;
bool is_unity;

desktop = getenv("XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP");                                     
is_unity = (desktop.toLower() == "unity");                             

if (is_unity) { 
  AppIndicator *indicator;
  GtkWidget *menu, *item;                                                       

  menu = gtk_menu_new(); 

  item = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label("Quit");                             
  gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(menu), item);                          
  g_signal_connect(item, "activate",                                          
               G_CALLBACK(quitIndicator), qApp);  // We cannot connect 
               // gtk signal and qt slot so we need to create proxy 
               // function later on, we pass qApp pointer as an argument. 
               // This is useful when we need to call signals on "this" 
               //object so external function can access current object                         
  gtk_widget_show(item);

  indicator = app_indicator_new(                                       
  "unique-application-name",                                                   
      "indicator-messages",                                                                  
    APP_INDICATOR_CATEGORY_APPLICATION_STATUS                                
  );                                                                         

  app_indicator_set_status(indicator, APP_INDICATOR_STATUS_ACTIVE); 
  app_indicator_set_menu(indicator, GTK_MENU(menu));   
} else {
  QSystemTrayIcon *icon;
  QMenu *m = new QMenu();                                                   

  m->addAction(tr("Quit"), qApp, SLOT(quit()));                      
}
```

Finally we create the proxy function to call Qt signal from it, to declare the function we need to use extern "C" so there will not be any undefined behaviour.

```
extern "C" {                                                                    
  void quitIndicator(GtkMenu *, gpointer);                                            
}
```

Now the proxy function:

```
void quitIndicator(GtkMenu *menu, gpointer data) {                                    
  Q_UNUSED(menu);                                                               
  QApplication *self = static_cast<QApplication *>(data);                       

  self->quit();                                                                 
}
```

Comment: I don't think GTK+ objects play nice with Qt's event loop. [This sample](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7687674/) results in [these errors](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7687666/).

Answer (score 5):

Just wanted to add, for anyone that is using Qt and trying to show a app indicator in Ubuntu 13+  as others have mentioned sni-qt is not working, I was able to use the above reply to make a Qt app that works, still trying to get the icon to change and show popup messages, but this is a great start, once i get the icon and message to work i might post it out on my site [Voidrealms.com](http://www.voidrealms.com):

Be sure to do `sudo apt-get install libappindicator-dev`

Make a new project with a QDialog in it and modify as seen below:

Pro file:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2014-03-28T20:34:54
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = PluginServiceGUI
TEMPLATE = app

# includes for the libappindicator
# /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu libglib-2.0.a

INCLUDEPATH += "/usr/include/libappindicator-0.1"
INCLUDEPATH += "/usr/include/gtk-2.0"
INCLUDEPATH += "/usr/include/glib-2.0"
INCLUDEPATH += "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include"
INCLUDEPATH += "/usr/include/cairo"
INCLUDEPATH += "/usr/include/pango-1.0"
INCLUDEPATH += "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include"
INCLUDEPATH += "/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0"
INCLUDEPATH += "/usr/include/atk-1.0"

LIBS += -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lgobject-2.0
LIBS += -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lappindicator
LIBS += -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lgtk-x11-2.0

#These seem to not be needed
#LIBS += -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lcairo
#LIBS += -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lpango-1.0
#LIBS += -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lglib-2.0

# end incudes for libappindicator


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        dialog.cpp

HEADERS  += dialog.h

FORMS    += dialog.ui

RESOURCES += \
    resources.qrc
```

In the main.cpp

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QSystemTrayIcon>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QSystemTrayIcon>
#include <QMenu>

// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17193307/qt-systray-icon-appears-next-to-launcher-on-ubuntu-instead-of-on-the-panel
// requires libappindicator-dev
// sudo apt-get install libappindicator-dev
// installs the headers in: /usr/include/libappindicator-0.1/libappindicator

#undef signals
extern "C" {
  #include <libappindicator/app-indicator.h>
  #include <gtk/gtk.h>

  void quitIndicator(GtkMenu *, gpointer);

}
#define signals public

void quitIndicator(GtkMenu *menu, gpointer data) {
  Q_UNUSED(menu);
  QApplication *self = static_cast<QApplication *>(data);

  self->quit();
}

void ShowUnityAppIndicator()
{
    AppIndicator *indicator;
    GtkWidget *menu, *item;

    menu = gtk_menu_new();

    item = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label("Quit");
    gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(menu), item);
    g_signal_connect(item, "activate",
                 G_CALLBACK(quitIndicator), qApp);  // We cannot connect
                 // gtk signal and qt slot so we need to create proxy
                 // function later on, we pass qApp pointer as an argument.
                 // This is useful when we need to call signals on "this"
                 //object so external function can access current object
    gtk_widget_show(item);

    indicator = app_indicator_new(
    "unique-application-name",
        "indicator-messages",
      APP_INDICATOR_CATEGORY_APPLICATION_STATUS
    );

    app_indicator_set_status(indicator, APP_INDICATOR_STATUS_ACTIVE);
    app_indicator_set_menu(indicator, GTK_MENU(menu));
}



void ShowQtSysTray(QApplication* app, QDialog* dialog)
{

    Q_INIT_RESOURCE(resources);

    if (!QSystemTrayIcon::isSystemTrayAvailable()) {
        QMessageBox::critical(0, QObject::tr("Systray"),
                              QObject::tr("I couldn't detect any system tray "
                                          "on this system."));
    }
    QApplication::setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(false);


    QSystemTrayIcon* trayIcon = new QSystemTrayIcon(dialog);
    QAction* Action = new QAction("hello", dialog);
    QMenu* trayIconMenu = new QMenu(dialog);

    trayIconMenu->addAction("Quit", app, SLOT(quit()));

    trayIconMenu->addAction(Action);
    trayIcon->setContextMenu(trayIconMenu);
    trayIcon->setIcon(QIcon (":/icons/Icons/accept.png"));

    trayIcon->show();
    trayIcon->showMessage("Title","Message");
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{



        QApplication a(argc, argv);
         Dialog w;

         //Determine the desktop type
         QString desktop;
         bool is_unity;

         desktop = getenv("XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP");
         is_unity = (desktop.toLower() == "unity");

         if(is_unity)
         {
            ShowUnityAppIndicator();
         }
         else
         {
             //Show the SystemTrayIcon the Qt way
             ShowQtSysTray(&a, &w);
         }

   // w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```